# Find the sub-string after nth '|'

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

Given a string as follows:

```
1|2||||auc|0|1||0|||76u|
      ^
```

what is the most efficient way to return the substring after the 5th '|'?
For example, given the above string, the result should be:

```
auc|0|1||0|||76u|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.split`:

```
s = '1|2||||auc|0|1||0|||76u|'
print s.split('|', 5)[-1]
# auc|0|1||0|||76u|
```

Note, this will cause possibly undesired results if there's not at least 5 `|`s, eg,

```
'1|2'.split('|', 5)[-1]
# returns 2 - which isn't *after* the 5th
```

present in the string, so you may wish to wrap it in a try/except and force handle the case where there aren't sufficient `|`s so that the result *after the 5th* is empty as there wasn't 5 present.

```
try:
    rest = s.split('|', 5)[5]
except IndexError:
    rest = ''
```

Comment: Nice and clean solution. If I may add some hopefully common knowledge for the record: If you have good reason to expect that a good portion of strings will have less than five pipes, you might want to split first and check the length of the result instead of catching the error.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`str.split()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with a limit (second argument):

```
input_string.split('|', 5)[-1]
```

This splits the string 5 times, and takes the last element, which has the remaining `|` charaters unsplit.

If there are *fewer* than 5 `|` characters in the string, you still will get the last element from the split, because `[-1]` counts from the end. This means the expression keeps working even if there are *zero* pipe symbols in the split.

Demo:

```
>>> input_string = '1|2||||auc|0|1||0|||76u|'
>>> input_string.split('|', 5)
['1', '2', '', '', '', 'auc|0|1||0|||76u|']
>>> input_string.split('|', 5)[-1]
'auc|0|1||0|||76u|'
```

and quoting the documentation:

> If *maxsplit* is given, at most *maxsplit* splits are done (thus, the list will have at most `maxsplit+1` elements).

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_substring(my_string):
    count = 0
    for i, char in enumerate(my_string):
        if char == '|':
            count += 1
            if count == 5:
                return my_string[i+1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '1|2||||auc|0|1||0|||76u|'
sre =  re.compile('([^|]*)(' + r*4 + ')(.*)')

sre.search(s).groups()
Out[39]: ('1', '|2|||', '|auc|0|1||0|||76u|')

sre.search(s).group(3)[1:]
Out[40]: 'auc|0|1||0|||76u|'
```